# Jquery: On mouseenter and mouseleave complete

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouseenter, mouseleave

Is there is any way to create complete event callback on mouse events? For example:

```
var process=function(event){//process event};
var complete=function(event){//on event complete,ends};

$('div').on('mouseenter',process,complete);
```

Thanks for help

Comment: why can't you just register mouseenter and mouseleave handlers - `$('div').mouseenter(process).mouseleave(complete);`

Comment: or use `$('div').hover(process,complete);`

Comment: @ArunPJohny The hover is $('div').hover( handlerIn, handlerOut ) as I see on Jquery documentation -  https://api.jquery.com/hover/
From you last edit I need something like: $('div').mouseenter(process,complete).mouseleave(process,complete); On each event I need to know when it finished... Does it possible?

Comment: So what do you mean by complete

Comment: What you're asking for is what `.hover()` does. https://api.jquery.com/hover/ `$('div').on('hover',process,complete);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseout()` events try something like this :

```js
$(function(){
  $( ".overout" )
    .mouseout(function() {
      $( "p:first", this ).text( "mouse out" );
    })
    .mouseover(function() {
      $( "p:first", this ).text( "mouse over" );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overout">
  <p style="background:#ff0; font-size:29px;">move your mouse</p>
</div>
```